# Any downsides for calling React Apollo Hooks from every component that needs it, instead of passing data from parent to children as props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

Taking a simple structure like this one :

```
<ComponentA><ComponentB /></ComponentA>
```

Where both components A & B needs the information fetch through a react apollo hook from a server :

```
const booksQuery = useGetBooks();
```

Is there any downside if components A & B both separately call `useGetBooks()` ? Or would it be better if only the component A calls it, and pass the value to it child component B using the props?

Here are a few points :

- Looking at my network, I do not see duplicated calls. I'm no expert, but I guess because of the Apollo cache?
- Duplicating the call seems to make component B easier to reuse.
- When the structure become deep, it is somewhat painful to pass props through multiple children.

Comment: Yeah it will the particular network request only hen the component mounts it may be an advantage or downside depending on your use case

Comment: @GayatriDipali This was my first concern, but as I stated in my message, this is the element I checked for. And even when both component are mount, I cannot seems to find two request in the network, always one. I'm under the impression Apollo provides some caching, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah apollo does cache data, look at the docs : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#:~:text=Apollo%20Client%20stores%20the%20results,without%20sending%20unnecessary%20network%20requests.